# RSpec-2 and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, devise, rspec2

i create a customized devise registration controller and i want to test it with rspec.

I've tried it with a very simple test :

```
it "creates a new parent" do
  Parent.should receive(:new)
  post :create
end
```

but i get this exception:

```
Failures:
  1) Parent::RegistrationsController POST create creates a new parent
     Failure/Error: post :create, { :commit => "Daftar",
     uncaught throw `warden'
     # /home/starqle/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/gems/devise-1.1.3/lib/devise/hooks/timeoutable.rb:16:in `throw'
     # /home/starqle/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/gems/devise-1.1.3/lib/devise/hooks/timeoutable.rb:16
```

I already put this line within my test:

```
describe Parent::RegistrationsController do
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end
```

I also already put this line:

```
request.env["devise_mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:parent]
```

anybody have ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: Oh, and one more thing.. It is only happens when i use sign_in method within my customized controller..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My previous answer is a little confusing. sorry.

Updated answer:   root cause is user is not "confirmed" before "sign in".

```
@user.confirm! 
sign_in @user
```

then everything is fine.

Comment: Yeah, it's not an elegant solution. I don't know if Rails3 guys met this problem. However I am sure that there are 2 sign_in methods in devise: 
1.  sign_in (Devise::Controllers::Helpers)
2.  sign_in (Devise::TestHelpers)

they used different implementation strategy, and only the 2nd method works.  I don't know if this is a bug, unless I have enough time to read "warden"'s source code. 

this is my first accepted answer on StackOverflow, thank you!

Comment: It seems I found the root cause: the @user should be first of all confirmed before sign_in.   @user.confirm!   
      sign_in(@user)

Comment: Siwei you ROCK! Thank you thank you thank you. I have been searching for hours for the solution to similar problem, and `@user.confirm!` before `sign_in @user` was exactly the piece I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

I am fresher in ruby.
I am using rails 3 with devise and factory girl.

I was searching for how to authenticate user for rspec.

I was stucked at before_filter: authenticate_user! in controller.

Finally I got solution (thanks to Siwei Shen)
What I am doing is

1. include TestHelpers in spec/spec_helper.rb

2.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe StudentsController do
  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory.create(:user)  #:user from factory girl with admin privilages
    @request.env['devise.mapping'] = :user
    @user.confirm!
    sign_in @user
  end

  it "can get index of student" do
    get :index
    response.should be_suclogin_as @user
  end

  it "can create student" do
    #in student model : validates :name, :presence=> true 
    post :create, :student => {name => "student1" } 
    answer = Student.find_by_name("student1")
    answer.name.should == "student1"
  end
end
```